# Take average of 90% of small duration with specific condition

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to take average of 90% of smallest numbers from one column with below conditions

- Group1 = "Major Metro" and "VIP Metro"
- Group2 = "ACCESS"
- Severity= "Medium"
- Include / Exclude = "Include"

Results will be = 51:22:00

I used separate formula and work but I don't know how to combined them

1st formula to calculate average for all with my conditions

```
=AVERAGE(IF((B:B="ACCESS")*(C:C="Medium")*(E:E="Include")*((A:A="Major Metro")+(A:A="VIP Metro")),D:D))
```

2nd formula to take average of 90% of smallest number

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"<"&PERCENTILE(D:D,0.9))/COUNTIF(D:D,"<"&PERCENTILE(D:D,0.9))
```

[image]

How to combine these two formulas or create new better one?

Comment: have you tried `AverageIfs`?

Comment: @gns100  That won't work given the need for an OR criteria in column A.  Without O365 that would mean having to resort to using SUMPRODUCT instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your first formula will not work the way you are intending.

your `IF(...)` statement is going to return an array that is a mix of D values and FALSE values that will error once embedded in an AVERAGE() function.

**If you have Excel O365,** I would consider using FILTER() with all of your various criteria:  (shown here using `alt` `returns` for clarity):

```
=average( FILTER(D:D,
(B:B="ACCESS")*
(C:C="Medium")*
(E:E="Include")*
((A:A="Major Metro")+(A:A="VIP Metro"))
)
```

Then you can get your 90 percentile by just adding the additional condition the way you already did the others:

```
=AVERAGE( FILTER(D:D,
(B:B="ACCESS")*
(C:C="Medium")*
(E:E="Include")*
((A:A="Major Metro")+(A:A="VIP Metro"))*
(D:D <= PERCENTILE.INC( D:D , 90% ))
)
```

**Without O365, *and* do *not* have Excel 2021** you will not be able to accomplish this with AVERAGEIF because you have an OR condition for column A, and AVERAGEIF requires only AND conditions.

Thus without Excel O365 you will have to use the SUMPRODUCT method.  In this method you use two SUMPRODUCTS...  One that sums an array of the values that meet the criteria, the other that sums the array of the logical result of your conditions.  The first array is the values that met the condition, the second array is a 1 for each row that met the conditions, and a zero for each row that didn't, and this results in a count.  There is the strong potential that you will divide by zero sometimes, so use of IFERROR or some zero handling is recommended.

The numerator is:

```
=SUPMPRODUCT( D:D *
(B:B="ACCESS")*
(C:C="Medium")*
(E:E="Include")*
((A:A="Major Metro") + (A:A="VIP Metro"))*
(D:D <= PERCENTILE.INC( D:D , 90% ))
)
```

And the dominator is the same WITHOUT the `D:D *` at the beginning:

```
=SUPMPRODUCT(
(B:B="ACCESS")*
(C:C="Medium")*
(E:E="Include")*
((A:A="Major Metro") + (A:A="VIP Metro"))*
(D:D <= PERCENTILE.INC( D:D , 90% ))
)
```

What you end up with is this monster all in one formula:

```
=SUPMPRODUCT( D:D *
(B:B="ACCESS")*
(C:C="Medium")*
(E:E="Include")*
((A:A="Major Metro") + (A:A="VIP Metro"))*
(D:D <= PERCENTILE.INC( D:D , 90% ))
) /
SUPMPRODUCT(
(B:B="ACCESS")*
(C:C="Medium")*
(E:E="Include")*
((A:A="Major Metro") + (A:A="VIP Metro"))*
(D:D <= PERCENTILE.INC( D:D , 90% ))
)
```

**If you *DO* have Excel 2021 but *not* Excel O365**

Then you'll be using the SUMPPRODUCT() approach.  But you can *dramatically* simplify the formula by encapsulating it in a LET() statement.  Once you learn your way around the LET() statement, and the habit of using `alt` `enter` to make LET()s more readable, you'll never go back.  Instead of repeating the conditions twice, you make them parameters inside a LET() statement.  This simplifies the formula, but quite importantly, in this case cuts the number of calculations in half.  Each parameter is calculated ONE time and remains persistent (and thus reusable) *within* that instance of the LET().  The whole SUMPRODUCT() formula becomes:

```
=LET(
selectedRowArray,
(B:B="ACCESS")*
(C:C="Medium")*
(E:E="Include")*
((A:A="Major Metro") + (A:A="VIP Metro"))*
(D:D <= PERCENTILE.INC( D:D , 90% )),
countOfRows, SUM( selectedRowArray ),
IF ( countOfRows, SUMPRODUCT(D:D, selectedRowArray) / countOfRows, 0 )
)
```

This also illustrates how I would incorporate error-checking that would catch when zero rows matched the criteria.  I put the divide inside an IF() statement that only executes if the denominator is not 0. Any value of countOfRows greater or equal to 1 will be interpreted as `TRUE` by the IF().

**Closing Thoughts**

1. I used `PERCENTILE.INC()` simply because it is the newer version of `PERCENTILE()`, which remains for compatibility.
2. The use of entire columns like `A:A` is something you can get away with casually but is definitely not a best practice for a sheet that will "live on" and be used over time.  It is fraught with complications...  (a) the performance hit of scanning over a million rows in each column; and (b) the risk that unintended content will end up somewhere in the column and be silently included in your result.  The best practice is, where possible, to use the Excel table construct if you need ranges that transparently accommodate row insertions.  (Thanks Jos)

Comment: It is not a good idea to reference entire columns in `SUMPRODUCT`, nor in `FILTER` or `PERCENTILE.INC`. None of those functions employs implicit detection of the last-used cells within the ranges passed. As such, just one instance of your last formula is being forced to process more than **15 million** calculations.

Comment: @JosWoolley Cannot agree more, I was thinking about adding that to the answer, and will now, thanks!

Comment: @MaxR ,,, for the benefit of the community,,, better add the LET formula ☺ +10

Comment: @RajeshSinha I thought about doing it, but…  If a person has access to  LET() then they usually (not always, but almost always) have access to FILTER().  Where the LET() really pays huge dividends is in the case where SUMPRODUCT() is used, which I would not use unless the preferred FILTER() was not available…  Which would most often mean LET() is also not available.

Comment: @MaxR ,,, not a bad idea if U do so,,, coz nowadays many are working with Off 2021 as well with 365 also ☺

Comment: @RajeshSinha OK, but there better be a lot of upvotes in it for me!  LOL

Comment: @MaxR ,, I think this is the correct version since OP is looking for 90% of small duration,,, =AVERAGE(FILTER(D34:D40,(B34:B40="ACCESS")*(C34:C40="Medium")*(E34:E40="Include")*((A34:A40="Major Metro")+(A34:A40="VIP Metro"))*(PERCENTILE.INC(SMALL(D34:D40,1),0.9))))

Comment: @RajeshSinha That can't be.  If the values are 1,2,3,4 and 5, then the smallest value is 1, and 90% of that is 0.9.  By definition there can *never* be any numbers that are 90% of the smallest number.  That's why I assumed the goal must be to find the smallest 90 percentile.